# I need help understanding part of a code - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have found the current code in relation to answering the question of finding the top two values in a list, however, I am having trouble understanding parts of the code and cannot find any help elsewhere. I was wondering if someone could tell me what the individual parts mean?

```
numbers = [20,67,3,2.6,7,74,2.8,90.8,52.8,4,3,2,5,7]
if numbers[0]>numbers[1]:
    m, m2 = numbers[0], numbers[1]
else:
    m, m2 = numbers[1], numbers[0]
for x in numbers[1:]:
    if x>m2:
        if x>m:
            m2, m = m, x # I am especially unsure of what is going on here
        else:
            m2 = x
```

m2 returns 74

Comment: Not sure if this question is on-topic, thereby I just comment. `m2, m = m, x` is equivalent to `m2 = m` and `m = x`. The code should return in `m` the biggest number of the list, in `m2` the second biggest number. At least two elements are assumed to exist, due to the first `if-else`.

Comment: its called parallel assignment. think like (m2, m) = (m, x).

Comment: While it is concise (and arguably pretty), parallel assignment (and redeclaration of variables) like `m2, m = m, x` is bound to cause confusion. [`Readability counts`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough pseudocode of what it is doing:

1. m will keep track of the largest variable in the list and m2 will keep track of the second largest.
2. Initially m and m2 will just be the first two elements in the list and m will be the bigger of the first two while m2 will be the smaller of the first two
3. Then you iterate over the list starting at index 1 and for each element x, you first check if it is bigger than the current m2. If it is, then you need to update m2 because it is no longer the second largest element. You also need to check if x is bigger than m (which should be the biggest element in the list) and if it is, update m to be x and m2 to be what m previously was

I have commented the code below with the explanation:

```
numbers = [20,67,3,2.6,7,74,2.8,90.8,52.8,4,3,2,5,7]   # list
# This part sets m1 and m2 to be the bigger of the first two elements in the list. 
# The notation m,m2 = numbers[0], numbers[1] is equivalent to m = numbers[0] followed by m2 = numbers[1]
if numbers[0]>numbers[1]:      
    m, m2 = numbers[0], numbers[1]
else:
    m, m2 = numbers[1], numbers[0]
for x in numbers[1:]:         # iterate over list start at index 1
    if x>m2:                  # if current element is greater than m2, we need to update m2
        if x>m:               # if current element is also greater than m, we need to set m2 to the value of m, and then update m to the new largest value which is x.
            m2, m = m, x      # This is doing m2 = m followed by m = x
        else:
            m2 = x            # if current element is greater than m2 but not m, just update m2 to x
```

The above code is nice and explicit so is good if you are starting with Python. There is also a one liner than will do this for you:

```
m, m2 = sorted(numbers, reverse=True)[:2]
```

Explanation:

```
sorted(numbers, reverse=True)                 # => returns sorted version of numbers [90.8, 74, 67, 52.8, 20, 7, 7, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2.8, 2.6, 2]
sorted(numbers, reverse=True)[:2]             # => splices the list to the first two elmems i.e [90.8, 74]
m, m2 = sorted(numbers, reverse=True)[:2]     # => Does the confusing multiple assignment as m = first element of the list and m2 = second element of the list
```

Comment: Thank you very much you have helped me to understand it! I had a thorough understanding of the beginning it was just when it started to use m2, m=m, x I was unsure of what the code was doing as I have not seen m=m harnessed in this way! Thanks

I also thought of using sorted which would have been the solution I put forward but I saw this solution and thought hey let's try and understand this!